# Java: How can I create a TimeZone object for Mountain time?

Tags: java, timezone

It is necessary that Daylight Savings is not disabled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265592/why-is-the-timezone-gettimezonemst-method-is-different-from-gettimezoneus - For the record only and help other developer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, in [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) of zoneinfo time zone names there are plenty which claim to be "Mountain Time". Find the one that best fits what you want, and use that. For example:

```
TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Denver");
```

Comment: +1 - java also accepts getTimeZone("US/Mountain") which to me is clearer - if you don't know the specific city, but I can't argue with the standard of names that you reference.  You could run into trouble if you picked a different city (ie Phoenix) with non-standard DST rules.

Comment: @RD01: I'd say that "America/Denver" is clearer precisely *for* that reason - because it's more precise, and therefore easier to predict. Given the various "mountain time" entries in the zoneinfo list, I wouldn't like to guess what I'd get just from using "US/Mountain".

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if you don't know what city you want, you can't be precise.  I'd rather have the generic Mountain which works for almost the entire zone, than a city that might have specific rules (although some of these are being phased out).  Picking the city is great when you're asking a user, who presumably knows.

Comment: @robert_x44 Those 3-4 letter abbreviations are not real time zones, not standardized, and are not unique(!). Use [proper time zone names](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format of `continent/region`. We are not saying the user lives in Denver, but rather the time zone for the entire *region* is named “America/Denver”.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Use [`ZoneId#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-) instead of [`Timezone#getTimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)) e.g.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Denver");
```

[<kbd>AN ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/4j1Ojj)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note:** Check [Mountain Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Time_Zone) and [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) and choose a timezone ID that meets your requirement.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>