# Why is the TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST") method is different from getTimeZone("US/Mountain")?

Tags: java

`TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Mountain")` and `TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST")` are returning different results. Does MST in this java class not represent "Mountain Standard Time"?

Comment: A quick look on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MST) gives three possible time zones that abbreviate to MST, so it doesn't look sound to rely on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use the short three letter names (`MST`) in Java. This has been deprecated since 1998 (see [JDK 1.3 TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)).

See [Sun Alert 102836](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/alert.html) for more info on some issues and workarounds, but you should really be using long names ("America/Denver" I believe in this case).

Comment: Actually, I am looking to convert Pacific time to Mountain Time (U.S. & Canada). Meanwhile I was confused with these two options. Thanks for pointing me to the deprecation.