# Current time not getting converted into MST timezone

Tags: java, date, time, timezone

I'm trying to convert current time in MST using below code

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
TimeZone toTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST");
sdf.setTimeZone(toTimeZone);
Date date = new Date();
String strDate = sdf.format(date.getTime());
```

strDate displaying correct MST time, but after parsing it is giving wrong date time.

```
Date currentDate = sdf.parse(strDate);
```

I want current MST time in Date format not in string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How can I create a TimeZone object for Mountain time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753484/java-how-can-i-create-a-timezone-object-for-mountain-time)

Comment: Give your input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A java.util.Date object does not have a concept of time zone.

- There is no way to set a timezone for a Date
- There is no way to change the timezone of a Date object
- A Date object created with the new Date() default constructor will be initialised with the current time in the system default timezone

All you did is add a time zone information for the *formatting* part... `setTimeZone` does not convert anything.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , DateTimeFormatter.forPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu hh:mm:ss" ) ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" ) );
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using old outmoded troublesome legacy date-time classes.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

## `LocalDateTime`

Your input string lacks any indication of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). So we must parse as a `LocalDateTime`. A `LocalDateTime` has no offset or time zone, so it does *not* represent a moment on the timeline. Like saying "Christmas starts at midnight on December 25", that only has meaning (only becomes a point on the timeline) when you apply it to a particular time zone somewhere on the planet.

```
String input = …
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.forPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu hh:mm:ss" );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you know the context and can assume the intended offset or time zone, you can create an [`OffsetDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) or [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) respectively.

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), named in the format of `continent/region`. By `MST` perhaps you meant the [`America/Denver`](http://time.is/Denver) time zone used in much of the Rocky Mountains parts of the United States, or [`America/Edmonton`](http://time.is/Edmonton) used in parts of Canada.

Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `MST`. These abbreviations are not true time zones, are not standardized, and are not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Denver" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zoneId ) ;
```

### Converting

I suggest avoiding the notoriously troublesome `java.util.Date` class. But if you must do so , you may [convert to/from java.time types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639154/convert-java-util-date-to-what-java-time-type). To interoperate with other code or libraries, convert using new methods added to the old classes. In this case, use a [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object extracted from the `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDatetime` and pass to [`java.util.Date.from`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-).

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
java.util.Date utilDate = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() ) ;
```

Going the other direction, use another new method added to the old class, [`java.util.Instant::toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--).

```
Instant instant = utilDate.toInstant();
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId ) ;
```